# why Seaport Opeansea testnets API return "null" for signature?

Tags: signature, opensea, eip712, api, seaport

I am trying to retrieve offers detail using [seaport API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieve-offers-testnets) for a given asset contract for a given token ID but it returns null for the signature field.
My understanding is that this signature is the signature from the offerer. and if I wanna accept the offer by calling the seaport `fulfillBasicOrder_efficient_6GL6yc` function or any other similar function to fulfill the order directly via etherscan I need to pass the signature.

My question is why is testnet API returning null for offer that is created and I can see on opeansea?

Also, what is the exact JSON format for an order that the offerer sign, I tried to create this signature locally for testnet by using [mycrypto/sign-message](https://app.mycrypto.com/sign-message)

I tried using parameter JSON (returned by API call) and stringify it but couldn’t pass fulfillBasicOrder_efficient_6GL6yc function call [transaction-simulator](https://tenderly.co/transaction-simulator)
it fails at Seaport. _assertValidSignature

```
{"offerer":"0xb1e020029EBAe05673Fc9166E12A8FC603da976C","offer":[{"itemType":1,"token":"0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6","identifierOrCriteria":0,"startAmount":"10000000000000000","endAmount":"10000000000000000"},{"itemType":2,"token":"0x6548606B21C1DE801dbD5497ce9796AfF3E48eE3","identifierOrCriteria":88,"startAmount":"1","endAmount":"1","recipient":"0xb1e020029EBAe05673Fc9166E12A8FC603da976C"},{"itemType":1,"token":"0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6","identifierOrCriteria":0,"startAmount":"250000000000000","endAmount":"250000000000000","recipient":"0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719"}],"startTime":1680858299,"endTime":1683450273,"orderType":0,"zone":"0x004C00500000aD104D7DBd00e3ae0A5C00560C00","zoneHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","salt":"24446860302761739304752683030156737591518664810215442929811069269589987966261","conduitKey":"0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000","counter":0}
```

Additionally, I am open to any alternative solutions that achieve the same goal. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: I ended up writing a script to generate signatures locally. Since it is testnet order for which I wanted a signature to fulfill, that belongs to me. so, it is possible to generate signatures locally for testing. I am using opensea-js.